# Grunt Performing Actions on a Static Directory of Files

Tags: gruntjs

I've been working to integrate grunt for the work I'm doing on my personal site.  However - it seems like it isn't designed to work well for my current implementation.  In short, I am using a static site generator (Wintersmith).  My desire is to have grunt to perform a series of actions (minify css, uglify for js, format HTML and remove empty lines) on this directory that was generated by the site generator.

In short here are my issues:

1. Grunt plugins seem to always have a different source and destination for files.  In my case, I just want it to take a file (for example, a CSS file) and have it be minified in the same file.
2. Grunt doesn't seem to handle situations where you want to perform an action on a series of files where each action would have a different output.  For example, if I want it to perform an action to format the generated HTML on all HTML files in a directory (without naming them each specifically) - then I can't.

I would like to use grunt in this case, but it seems like I'd just be better off writing a shell script for this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Just specify the same path in `src` and `dest`.
2. Yes you can. See [Building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

Example copied from the docs:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  minify: {
    dynamic_mappings: {
      // Grunt will search for "**/*.js" under "lib/" when the "minify" task
      // runs and build the appropriate src-dest file mappings then, so you
      // don't need to update the Gruntfile when files are added or removed.
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
          cwd: 'lib/'       // Src matches are relative to this path.
          src: ['**/*.js'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
          dest: 'build/',   // Destination path prefix.
          ext: '.min.js',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

*This pertains to Grunt 0.4*

Comment: This is certainly getting me a lot closer.  Question - If you have files (like all HTML files that are in a subdirectory which also has multiple directories in it) - can you specify that they are output in the same folder structure that it found them in?  So if I want to run a format HTML task - and I have 3 files - index.html some_dir/index.html and some_other_dir/file.html .  Is there a way I can build those dynamically and have them output in the correct folder?  I'm not seeing that in the docs.

Comment: That's exactly what the above config does. The two stars is a globbing pattern for recursively looking in all subfolders.